# Crystal Reports - Unable to connect on PC's other than my own and another developer

Tags: c#, sql-server, authentication, crystal-reports, connection

I built a report in Visual Studio 2010 using Crystal Reports for .net framework 4.0

All operator machines have the runtime CR13 for .net framework 4.0 installed on their machines.

When this report is run in the application through the report viewer, I can view and interact with it.  The other programmer on this project can also do this.  If we log off our machines and log onto our machine under another user's network credentials, reports work just fine.

However, if we use another operators PC and pull up the report, they are prompted to provide credentials.  This should not happen due to integrated security and the server field is also blank and grayed out.

Ive been fighting with this for hours and I am out of ideas.  It works on the dev machines but not on operator machines and they have crystal reports 13 for .net framework 4.0 runtime installed, the same one used to build these reports.

Anybody have any ideas, i'll try anything at this point...

So far I've tried:

- Logging in as others on my machine, everyone works on my machine
- Giving users full permissions on the database, no luck
- Manually creating a connection in the code to set to my crystal report viewer to try to force this to work, no luck there

Comment: Are your operators on a separate network/domain from yourselves?  Do they need to do a 'double hop' authentication? Have you logged on as yourself on your user's machine?

Comment: We are all on the same network, I cannot access these reports as myself on their machines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create ODBC connections rather than using OLEDB.  Problem was solved 100%, although I don't think my network admins liked having these added to all the machines in the department.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that the problem the connection string of the report. Is set to integrated authority? Try setting up a Report Only type user with select rights to the appropriate tables, and setting the connection string to use that login explicitly.

Edit - Are you connecting to an Oracle database? Make sure your drivers are up today, I've had huge headaches from that in the past.

Comment: SQL Server 2005. The report has setup all of that already I don't need to specify my own connection string